# Bootstrap modal not refreshing for django view on test server

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am aware that in BS 3, when calling a modal dialog, you would need to insert the following js to remove the modal's data when hiding it if you load an external page into the modal:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#ModalID', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

I load the modal using this:

```
$('.select-modal').click(function(ev) {
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#ModalID').modal({
    show: true,
    remote: url
});
return false;
```

Which loads a TemplateView with a context containing images:

```
class ImageSelectView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'imageviewer/image_modal.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ImageSelectView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['images'] = Image.objects.for_user(self.request.user).order_by('-created')
        return context
```

It works okay on my development machine, new items added to Image show up. On the production server, changes are not reflected within the modal. I have tried clearing Memcache, clearing browser cache, tried different ways of loading the url etc.

Comment: why `.on('hidden.bs.modal'` ??

Comment: Check you get any errors for that request.

Comment: Maybe you use the wrong 'href' attribute? For example, containing `localhost`?

Comment: Gupta: when modal is hidden the data originally loaded is removed. Rohan: no errors for request. Alexander: nope not using the wrong href. Strangely the cache issue happens sporadically. Most likely a cache problem somewhere.

Comment: Alright. Spotted the error. I was calling some extra js files from within the modal which may have caused some caching issues. Not exactly sure what they are but after moving the references outside to the main html file, it seems to be working fine for now.